# How to set relax controls on a LDAP context

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, openldap

I would like to set the *relax* control (as defined in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-zeilenga-ldap-relax-03) on a `javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext`, but I don't know how to construct the control correctly:

```
LdapContext context = new InitialLdapContext(...);
Control[] controls = { new BasicControl(/* What to put here? */) };
context.setRequestControls(controls);
```

Comment: You need to write a class that extends `BasicControl`, and implements all the required ASN.1 stuff to encode and decoder. Not a trivial task given the lack of support for ASN.1 in the official JDK.

Comment: Thanks, but fortunately it was trivial, as no specific control value was needed (see my answer). Btw. there is a `BerEncoder` and `BerDecoder` in the official JDK - only partial official, as it belongs to com.sun... - which at least helps handling ASN values.

Comment: I;m aware of that, and have written code with it, but I don't like relying on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunately I found a part of the answer in the draft itself:

> The Relax Rules control is an LDAP Control [RFC4511] whose
>   controlType   is IANA-ASSIGNED-OID, controlValue is empty, and the
>   criticality of TRUE.

So the only problem was to find the *IANA-ASSIGNED-OID*

Looking in the source of OpenLdap 2.4.40 (include/ldap.h) this is:

```
#define LDAP_CONTROL_RELAX              "1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.5.12"
```

Now this is working:

```
LdapContext context = new InitialLdapContext(...);
Control[] controls = { new BasicControl(
    "1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.5.12", // OID
    true, // criticality
    null // control value
) };
context.setRequestControls(controls);
```

It's important to notice that this OID belongs to the *OpenLDAP Experimental Arc (1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666)* and may change in future versions of OpenLDAP.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case you need to write a class that extends BasicControl, and implements all the required ASN.1 stuff to encode and decoder. Not a trivial task given the lack of support for ASN.1 in the official JDK.

However as this control is trivial:

```
import javax.naming.ldap.BasicControl;

/**
 * Relax Rules control
 * @author Esmond Pitt
 * @see <a href="https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-zeilenga-ldap-relax-03">The Relax Rules Control</a>
 * @see <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080294/how-to-set-relax-controls-on-a-ldap-context">Stack Overflow</a>
 */
public class RelaxRulesControl extends BasicControl
{
    /** The OID, see Tobias's answer for provenance. */
    public static final String  OID = "1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.666.5.12";

    /** Construct an instance with criticality = true */
    public RelaxRulesControl()
    {
        super(OID, true, null);
    }

    /** Construct an instance with critically as specified */
    public RelaxRulesControl(boolean critical)
    {
        super(OID, critical, null);
    }
}
```